# Colorize text without using html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have the following text:

```
"<Name>Tom</Name>"
```

Normally, to colorize the text, I would do the following (or use a library like Prism to do this):

```
<span class="tag">
    &lt;Name&gt;
</span>
Tom
<span class="tag">
    &lt;/Name&gt;
</span>
```

And then add a css property such as `span.tag { color: red }`

I was wondering if it is possible at all to colorize the text **without** marking up the html itself. I believe the answer is no, but I was wondering if perhaps you can apply css based upon a regex/string position?

Comment: Did you try in-line style attribute? i.e. `style="color:red"` ?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl still, wouldn't you need to add a span or some element to do inline styling?

Comment: Can you modify the HTML via javascript?

Comment: That's right, you would need any syntax highlighter like Prism

Comment: is that text part of any element - div, span, li ?

Comment: you may do with single span <span style="color:red">&lt;Name&gt;Tom&lt;/Name&gt;</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can at least access a single object for the output, this works.

```js
var str = "<Name>Tom</Name>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;
var names = document.getElementsByTagName("Name");

for(x = 0;x<names.length;x++){
 var newEl = document.createElement('span');
 newEl.innerHTML = "&lt;Name&gt;<span class='value'>" + names[x].innerHTML + "</span>&lt;/Name&gt;";
 names[x].parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, names[x]);
}
```

```css
span{color:red;}
span .value{color:black;}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
span:before {
    color: red;
    content: "<Name>";
}

span:after {
    color: red;
    content: "</Name>";
}
```

```html
<span>Tom</span>
```